# iid data (Bayesian) vs iid random variables (Frequentist)?

Tags: bayesian, notation, frequentist, philosophical

I've been pondering the differences in notation / language used in some of the resources I've read for statistics / machine learning.

**Warning**: this might be embarrassingly obvious to any decent statistician, so apologies in advance.

### 1 iid data (Bayesian)

I am a big fan of [Pattern Recognition for Machine Learning](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/pattern-recognition-machine-learning/) (Bishop) so much of my foundation in basic statistical machine learning comes from there. In the first chapter (section 1.2.4, page 26), he takes the approach of defining a scenario where we have a random variable $x$ and the data  $\pmb{\mathsf{x}} = \{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ are $N$ independently drawn observations of the random variable $x$.

To emphasize...a set of data is seen as a number of observations of the *same random variable*. My claim is that this approach to setting up the data / statistical problem is kind of **Bayesian** and this is corroborated (somewhat) by the fact that Bishop seems to be a Bayesian.

This also seems Bayesian to me because we're *setting* the data in stone. That is, our data is not a set of random variables but a set of realizations of a single random variable which falls in line with Bayesian philosophy.

### 2 iid random variables (Frequentist)

Contrast this with a more frequentist resource such as Larry Wasserman's [intermediate statistics notes](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=stat705/). Throughout the lectures, we consider instead a set of random variables $X_1, ..., X_N$ that are i.i.d in that they are independent and follow the same exact distribution.

Data is seen as a set of *random variables*, **not** a set of realizations of a random variable. This lends itself to constructing "estimators" and asymptotics because we view the dataset as random. It can be constructed many times by realizing the set of random variables $X_1, ..., X_N$ simultaneously many times. Then you can do analysis of the long-run behaviour of doing an experiment many times which I believe is quite Frequentist.

I suppose my question is: **what are the relative merits of using either approach to denoting the data? And does this directly coincide with the merits of Bayesianism vs Frequentism?**? I am biased and prefer the **Bayesian** setup because (i) I'm used to it, and (ii) it allows (in my opinion) for much less "terminological" overhead that often creates abusive notation and then confusion. However, it does seem like there is a much easier segway into things like asymptotics (maybe other stuff I'm not mentioning) if we view the dataset as random.

Of course, please point out any errors! Thanks.

**Edit**: I defer to this [explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508065/when-i-repeat-an-experiment-10-times-do-i-have-10-different-random-variables-al) from Christian Hennig.

Comment: *"a number of observations of the same random variable"* this is not very clear and it sounds more like a play with words and definitions 'when do we call something a variable or not?' leading to semantic discussions where the underlying principles and concepts are not different but the one calls it a 'realization' and the other a 'variable'. I doubt whether you are describing an actual difference and some practical example to make it more clear might be useful.

Comment: In my mind this means -- suppose you have a random variable $x$ that follows a univariate Gaussian distribution. You sample from this distribution a number $N$ times to yield $N$ observations of that random variable. An example could be as simple as the random variable representing height of humans on earth. Going out and recording $N$ measurements would yield $N$ observations of that random variable.

Comment: The $N$ observations, like the height of a sample of $N$ randomly selected humans, whether you call that '$N$ variables' or '$N$ realisations of a variable', does that matter? The nature of the observations remains the same and it is just the label/name that changes.

Comment: It does matter (in my mind). First I think **variable** $\neq$ **random variable**. I like to think of "realizations" as actual values as a result of "realizing" or "observing" a random variable (e.g. measuring it). I guess my question is about this use of this language and the philosophical motivations for choosing such language.

Comment: Paul, in a frequentist approach, one can just as well think about data as realizations of some random process/variable. In your example, whether you call it realizations or random variables, the concepts are the same with only different labels/names. You have to be very precise here and describe what you exactly mean, in order to prevent to be describing some difference that doesn't actually exist and is just a use of different words.

Comment: *"Data is seen as a set of random variables, not a set of realizations of a random variable."* where is this viewpoint relevant when applying frequentist methods? The premise behind your question, that there is a difference in viewing data as not being realizations, might be false.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus thank you for your reply. The reason I started this question was when reading the last section (section 7) of this (assumably frequentist) [lecture on statistics](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture1.pdf). As an example, when we view our dataset as random variables, we can define the transformation $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where $X_i$ is a *random variable*. Here, $\hat{\mu}$ is itself a random variable. If $X_i$ were instead realizations of random variables, $\hat{\mu}$ is a number/value. Let me know if this clears that up?

Comment: So if the $X_i$ are random variables then a transformation like $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ is a random variable, and if the $X_i$ are realizations of  a random variable then a transformation like $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ is a realization of a random variable. So far it is just two separate statements, without a clear indication what the problem is with it. If the statistic $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ is itself a random variable or a random realization, then what is the problem and how would a frequentist or Bayesian approach conflict with this?

Comment: I agree they are two separate statements. My question was, given that I've seen a statistical problem being set up in the two different ways (the "realization" one in Bayesian texts, and the "random variable" in Frequentist texts), I wanted to know what the point is to setting up the problem in these two different ways and if it is directly linked with the differing statistical philosophies. Perhaps my question was misguided / too vague.

Comment: I don't see how your example with $\hat\mu$ and with human heights makes an example of how Bayesian and frequentist analysis consider data different. You say that frequentist approaches consider the data as variables instead as realizations of variables. Fine, you can label it as such, but what does that mean? How is it different except for a different name or label?

Comment: *"given that I've seen a statistical problem being set up in the two different ways"* how is the setup different, except that the two cases just use different names for data, the one calling it a 'random variable' and the other a '(random) realization'?

Comment: In a Bayesian setting, elements of a sample are *conditionally* independent and unconditionally *exchangeable*. The keyword `exchangeability` may be helpful when seeking the distinction between Bayesian and frequentist paradigms.

Comment: @paul: We cannot sample from a random variable $x$ $n$ times, I think that is where you go wrong. If we have $n$ observation, that is modelled as $n$ random variables, maybe iid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some back-and-forth with @Tim and @Sextus Empiricus (thank you both!) I think I have a clearer answer to my question:

First let's get notation down:

- $X_i$ is a random variable.
- $x_i$ is the realized value of observing/measuring $X_i$. It is a fixed number.
- $\mathbf{X} = \{X_1, ..., X_N\}$ is a set of i.i.d random variables. This is a set of random variables.
- $\pmb{\mathsf{x}} = \{x_1, ..., x_N\}$ is a set or realizations of the random variables $\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$. This is a set of fixed numbers.

It would seem that the following is technically **incorrect** (as Bishop does): "we have a random variable $X$ and the data $\pmb{\mathsf{x}} = \{x_1, ...,x_n\}$ are $N$ independently drawn observations of the random variable $X$". Once a random variable is observed, you cannot observe it again. So, technically speaking, this is does not make true mathematical sense.

The technically correct way to denote a *fixed* dataset (as Bayesians do) is to say: we have a set of realizations $\pmb{\mathsf{x}} = \{x_1, ..., x_N\}$ corresponding to observing the set of i.i.d random variables $\{X_1, ..., X_N\}$. A potential alternative to denote a fixed dataset (as Bayesian do) is to say: we have a set of values $\{x_1, ..., x_N\}$ that were all independently sampled from the same distribution $p(x)$.

What you'll often see in Frequentist texts is a dataset that is not yet realized (because they treat the dataset as random). Something like: we have a set of data comprised of i.i.d random variables $\{X_1, ..., X_N\}$. The benefit of this is that we can remark on properties of these data as they were random variables. For example, we can explore the properties of "estimators" which are functions of the *random* variables.

Comment: Exactly, +1! But bayesians also treat the sample as random, how else could they get a likelihood function?

Answer (score 4):

There are no two definitions or usage of the term. The only valid way of understanding "i.i.d. data" is the second "frequentist", as you call it, way. The only thing that could have distributions that could be independent are random variables. The only things that could have conditional distribution, or joint distribution, that makes a likelihood function in a Bayesian setting, are random variables. It is not data that is independent and identically distributed, but the random variables that we consider the data to be the realizations of which.

On the referred page 26, the the author uses the following example to illustrate it:

> Because our data set $\mathbf{x}$ is i.i.d., we can therefore write the probability of the data set, given $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ in the form
> $$
> p(\mathbf{x}|\mu,\sigma^2)=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal{N}(x_i|\mu,\sigma^2)
> $$

So *each* $x_i$ follows a normal distribution and their joint distribution is a product because $x_i$s are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)). They need to be random variables for that.

Also, notice that the Bayes theorem tells us that we can obtain

$$
p(\mu,\sigma^2|\mathbf{x}) \propto
p(\mathbf{x}|\mu,\sigma^2)\,
p(\mu)\,
p(\sigma^2)
$$

You can condition only on random variables, so if $\mathbf{x}$ would not be a random variable, the conditional probability would not be possible.

Comment: It could be added that in the frequentist as well as the Bayesian setup, once the data are observed, the values taken by them or realisations are no longer random variables but fixed, normally distinguished by lower case letters $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ from the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Could you add what you think Bishop then means when he sets up his problems? He usually describes data as being $N$ observations of a random variable drawn independently from the distribution that random variable follows. He then calls the dataset "i.i.d" (See first paragraph of page 26 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf)). This seems in direct contrast to when you say "the only valid way of understanding "i.i.d" data is the second frequentist". Thank you!

Comment: @paul I cannot talk for Bishop, but as I said, if you are not considering your data as random variables, you cannot have probabilistic models for them. Nonetheless, see the edit.

Comment: Thank you @Tim! I wanted to point our that your example does not faithfully represent what Bishop says, and this indeed lies at the heart of my question: Bishop uses a different boldface $\pmb{\mathsf{x}}$ in the likelihood $p(\pmb{\mathsf{x}}|\mu, \sigma^2)$. This $\pmb{\mathsf{x}}$, as I mentioned in the last comment, denotes (what Bishop says) is $N$ observations of a **single** random variable $x$. To me this makes sense because  $\pmb{\mathsf{x}}$ is our dataset and is *fixed* which is true in practice.

Comment: @Tim regarding your statement that if we don't consider data to be random variables, you cannot have probabilistic models for them -- I would like to get your thoughts on the following. In Bayesian statistics, we see the data as arising from a random process, but if we have a dataset it cannot be a random variable -- it is a bunch of fixed values that we posit *came from measuring a random variable*. If the parameters are treated as random (for example $\mu$ and $\sigma$), then the uncertainty comes from that, not repeated collections of our data.

Comment: @paul if $\mathbf{x}$ is a "single random variable", then ok, let us just this terminology, but from the definitions that Bishop gave, $\mathbf{x}$ is a random vector consisting of $N$ random variables, itself is a random variable. If that is what you mean then there is no disagreement.

Comment: Yes $\mathbf{x}$ is a random vector / random variable. However $\pmb{\mathsf{x}}$ (this is a different typeface:  Latex - \pmb{\mathsf{x}}) is $N$ realizations of the scalar random variable $x$ (see top of page 26).

Comment: @paul this statement does not make mathematical sense. If $\mathbf{x}$ is a random vector of size $N$, it consists of $N$ random variables. If they are realizations, not random variables, it is not a random vector, but a just vector of numbers. It also cannot consist of the same random variable "repeated" $N$ times, unless you mean that it is the same value repeated $N$ times. Random variables do not have multiple realizations unless you are trying to discuss some kind of parallel universes.

Comment: @Tim I'm not creating anything new - I am simply taking directly from Bishop's notation. It seems as though your answer is that you think Bishop has written things that make no mathematical sense. Regarding "random variables do not have multiple realizations", this goes in direct contrast to what Bishop says **at the top of page 26**. I would argue that (maybe from a Bayesian standpoint?) a random variable is a mapping from outcomes to a numerical value. Take $X = 0$ if coin flip is heads, $X=1$ if coin flip is tails. If you flip the coin multiple times, you get multiple realizations of $X$?

Comment: @paul You seem to be misunderstanding what we mean by random variables. In the coin flip example, $X$ does not represent a coin, but an experiment. If I toss the coin that I hold in my hand in 10 seconds from now, I can represent the possible outcomes of the toss as a random variable with two possible outcomes. The result of the toss would be a realization of the random variable. If I toss the coin again, it would be another experiment and another random variable. $N$ tosses could be represented as $N$ i.i.d. random variables, that is, $N$ independent variables following the same distribution.

Comment: @Tim thank you for this! I agree with this statement. I was just confused because of the language Bishop uses. He seems to think that each toss is an observation of a single random variable. It would appear you simply disagree with him, and perhaps you're right!

Comment: @Tim Is "you can condition only on random variables" formally correct, though? There is no mention whatsoever of events in this answer, and AFAIK that is what probabilities are conditioned on and what they measure. Whether the event that is being conditioned on is random or fixed would not be relevant. Or if we are talking about the sigma-algebra induced by a random variable, and we replace probabilities by CDFs, whether the set of outcomes $\omega$ such that $X(\omega) < x$ are seen as random or fixed, the event will have the same measure, no?

Comment: @Kuku I do not think that mentioning sigma algebra while answering a simple question would be helpful for the reader. The point I'm trying to make is that you cannot condition on fixed quantities.

Comment: @Tim I agree that a sigma algebra is not relevant to the question, but was looking to clarify the implications of your answer. Particularly, that the event we refer to by $X(\omega) = x$ is the same whether $x$ is fixed or random, no?

Comment: @Kuku I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: @Tim just making the point that to say that we "can only condition on random variables" might be confusing or misleading. We condition on events, and events are not random or fixed per se.  Whether we take it that the event has happened already or that it is uncertain, does not make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

> he takes the approach of defining a scenario where we have a random variable $x$ and the data  $\pmb{\mathsf{x}} = \{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ are $N$ independently drawn observations of the random variable $x$.

What's in a name? That which we call $X_i \underset{iid }{\sim} N(0,1)$ by any other name would just be as random.

Call it 'multiple realizations of a variable' or 'multiple variables drawn from a distribution/population', it doesn't matter. Bishop doesn't define the problem/situation by calling it 'observations of a single variable' it is the name that he calls it that becomes defined as the situation that he describes.

Answer (score -4):

Data are never "drawn from a distribution." Real data are outcomes from measurements, and hence ontological.

Probability distributions come from models; they exist only in our heads, hence epistemological. We can adopt one as a working hypothesis, but we are never certain whether they are true.

There are no random variables in Bayesian theory, only probability distributions.

However, when you adopt a probability distribution, of course, you can draw random samples from it, and analyze them as if they were data. But beware that these are not real data. Real data are different; they hide unexpected quirks.

Bishop's PRML is an excellent book for learning a lot of Bayesian methods. However, in Chapter 1, Bishop adopts a frequentist approach, which does a disservice to the remainder of his book.